# How do I web scrape in R for data that is presented in a chart?

Tags: r, web-scraping, charts, stock

For example, on this website:

https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/476915/braincool

I have been trying to web scrape the following:
Data from each day, of the opening, highest, lowest and closing value:

E.g. the values that have been highlighted in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFLC5.png

I have had some success with web scraping but then with actual number from a website, but the problem here is that the numbers are presented in the graphical form.
But is there a way to scrape those values?

I have tried using the rvest package to web scrape information for other sites, which as worked, but the way the data is presented on the website provided, I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the network section in the developer tools and you will find the API that the site is calling to retrieve information.

```
library(httr2)
library(tidyverse)

"https://www.avanza.se/_api/price-chart/stock/476915?timePeriod=today" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  getElement("ohlc") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange(-timestamp)

# A tibble: 39 x 6
       timestamp  open close   low  high totalVolumeTraded
           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>             <int>
 1 1668168660000  1.51  1.53  1.51  1.53             15071
 2 1668168600000  1.51  1.51  1.51  1.51              5000
 3 1668168480000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53              1940
 4 1668168420000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53               128
 5 1668168300000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53              5000
 6 1668168180000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53               100
 7 1668167880000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53             30000
 8 1668167640000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53             36460
 9 1668167340000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53             16793
10 1668167280000  1.53  1.53  1.53  1.53               867
# ... with 29 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```